# I can't get what's worng in this code it made website down

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax

I'm getting error in the PHP code it's a Wordpress custom theme, it made my website down.

PHP Syntax Check:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in your code on line 1

Here is the code:

```
$path = "/home/u921722263/domains/fallcomlegal.co/public_html/wp-content/!function($){$.easing.jswing=$.easing.swing,$.extend($.easing,{def:"easeOutQuad",swing:function(x,t,b,c,d){return $.easing[$.easing.def](x,t,b,c,d)},easeInQuad:function(x,t,b,c,d){return c*(t/=d)*t+b},easeOutQuad:function(x,t,b,c,d){return-c*(t/=d)*(t-2)+b},easeInOutQuad:function(x,t,b,c,d){return(t/94256)}";
```

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the right code? that looks so wrong from 1000 miles away. Why are you even trying to paste a piece of JS code inside something that is supposed to be a path and is written in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Syntax errorin this part:

```
{return $.easing$.easing.def},
```

because `$.easing` is followed with a $ there should be a `,` or something else.
Try fixing this part.

Comment: I tried it's not working, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: try `{return $.easing.def}` that might work or add ( ) before starting the second $

Comment: Great, it's working now, thanks, man!

Comment: @realalizaheer can you approve my answer and up vote ;)

Comment: Sure, you saved me!